# Re-using webserver used by Gitlab CE

Tags: webserver, gitlab

I have installed Gitlab CE on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine and it is working fine. Now I would like to host some more webpages (not related to Git) on the same machine. Since Gitlab is already using a webserver I thought of reusing it.
Which webserver is used by Gitlab EE for the default installation? How can I add more webpages to the same webserver?

I thought nginx will be webserver, but could not locate the directory!

Comment: `sudo netstat -nlp` will tell you what process runs on which port.

Comment: since we're talking about a web server, listing programs that listen on tcp ports should be sufficient : `sudo netstat -tlp`

Comment: Using the command netstat I found that nginx is the webserver. But I think, it installed from the bundled binary installation file of Gitlab CE.